# how to upload Code coverage report for PL/SQL Code to Sonarqube and to Teamcity?

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity

i have generated Code coverage report for PL/SQL Code with utplsql but i don t how to upload it to Sonarqube and then to Teamcity ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you use SonarQube is to drive scans of your source code from build automation, using one of the tools written to run the scan.  Two choices are the maven "sonar:sonar" goal, and the "sonar-scanner" tool.  Both of these have command-line properties that specify the location of the "lcov.info" file.  SonarQube will then produce a scan report that you can view from its user interface.